# PYOMO: ERROR:pyomo.core:Constructing component 'service' from data=None failed: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be has

Tags: python, optimization, location, allocation, pyomo

I am currently working on facility location - allocation problem using Pyomo for optimization. However, I stumbled upon the following problem. Here is a glimpse of my code:

```
modified_nodes = [1,3,5,7]
modified_arcs = [(1,3),(3,5),(5,7)]
car_class = ["a","b","c"]
full_charge_time = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
arrival_rate = {(1,8,1,1,3,"a"):1,(1,8,1,3,5,"a"):2, (1,8,1,5,7,"a"):3}
qrjk = [(1,8,1,1,3),(1,8,1,3,5),(1,8,1,5,7)]
potential_locations: {(1,8,1,1,3,"a"):[5,6,7],(1,8,1,3,5,"a"):[6,7,8], (1,8,1,5,7,"a"):[8,9,10]}

#Set nodes
model.Nodes = Set(initialize = modified_nodes)

#Define the arc
model.Arcs = Set(initialize = modified_arcs, within = model.Nodes*model.Nodes)

#Define set of transportation mode
model.Vehicles = Set(initialize = list(car_class))

model.lam = Var(model.Nodes, model.qrjk, model.Vehicles, within = Binary)
model.arrival = Param(model.qrjk, model.Vehicles, initialize = arrival_rate, default = 0)
model.charge_time = Param(model.Vehicles, initialize = full_charge_time, default = 0)
model.y = Var(model.Nodes, domain = PositiveIntegers)

def service_rule (model,i):
    return model.y[i] >= sum(model.charge_time [veh] * model.arrival [o,d,r,j,k,veh] * model.lam [i,o,d,r,j,k,veh] for o,d,r,j,k,veh in model.potential_locations)

model.service = Constraint(model.Nodes, rule = service_rule)
```

however, the following problem appeared:
ERROR:pyomo.core:Constructing component 'service' from data=None failed:
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I dont know what's wrong in my code. I checked each model parameters and variables, and it ran smoothly well

Thank you very much for your response

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough code to troubleshoot this.  Typically if you are having trouble with an error, it is customary to include **enough code to reproduce the error** rather than a "glimpse".  My suspicion is you are doing something with `pandas` that you aren't showing in the code.  Please edit your code and provide enough detail to actually reproduce the error if it is cut/pasted/executed.